# table view cell not appearing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom cell view and I made a default image in the story board. But for some reason my cell is not appearing. What should I do to make my cell appear.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as? TableViewCell {
        return cell
    }
    else{
        return TableViewCell()
    }
 }
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet  weak var mainImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainLbl: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
}

func configureCell(image: UIImage, text: String){
    mainImg.image = image
    mainLbl.text = "Hello Im Tyree"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed setting this in your `viewDidLoad()` :

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

So all of your tableView function code will never be excuted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the delegate, datasource is connected with your tableview in
   xib.
2. There is no function call for **func configureCell**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you dont neet to check that a cell with the identifier exists because it ALWAYS should. And set the property's of the cell in the cell for row at index path, not in the custom subclass. Also you need to set the delegate and datasource in the view did load

```
viewDidLoad() {
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

    cell.mainImg.image = image
    mainLbl.text = "Hello im tryee"

 return cell
} 
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 1
}
```

and the subclass should be

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet  weak var mainImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainLbl: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```